# Grade calculator using numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

[Question on Grade Calculator using Python Numpy](https://github.com/shkshreyas/pycode.py/blob/main/grade_calculator_python_numpy.py)

[I tried the following code in GitHub kindly correct it](https://github.com/shkshreyas/pycode.py/blob/main/grade_calculator_python_numpy.py)
Try the above question and suggest if you know some mor techniques and methods to solve it in a easy way. Also you can edit my code in GitHub

Comment: What is this *supposed* to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share all your code as formatted code in your question and not as links to your code. Please also add more details on what your issue is along with the input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code:

```
from numpy import *
a=array([[100,90,80,70,60,50,45],[90,80,70,60,50,40,30]])
L=["S", "A","B","C","D","E","F"]
n=int(input("Enter Marks Scored by Students: "))
for i in range(len(L)):
    if a[0][i]>n and a[1][i]<n:
        b=L[i]
print("Grade",b)
```

I have some comments on this:

```
from numpy import *
```

This is generally considered bad practice because it imports all of the functions from numpy into your namespace which can cause problems and overwite existing functions, especially if you start defining your own functions in larger projects.
Better practice would be

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([...])
```

```
if a[0][i]>n and a[1][i]<n:
```

This condition is flawed. For example, if a student scores 90, 90 is neither less than 90 nor greater than 100 and will not be assigned a grade. Additionally, it's best practice to anticipate edge cases in your conditional statement. For example, inputting a score of 20, which is out of range, results in a NameError since b is not defined.

```
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

I have provided an improved snippet below and have commented my changes:

```
# Import the numpy library and give it an alias 'np' for easier referencing.
import numpy as np

# Create a 2D numpy array where the first row represents the upper bounds of grades and the second row represents the lower bounds.
a = np.array([[100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 45], [90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30]])
L = ["S", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
n = int(input("Enter Marks Scored by Students: "))

# Create a mask (Boolean array) where each element is True if the student's score falls within the corresponding grade boundary.
grade_mask = (a[1] <= n) & (n < a[0])

# Find the index (position) of the grade boundary that the student's score falls into.
index = np.where(grade_mask)[0]

# If there's a match (i.e., the student's score falls within one of the grade boundaries), assign the corresponding grade label. Otherwise, assign "Invalid Score".
if index.size > 0:
    grade = L[index[0]]
else:
    grade = "Invalid Score"

print("Grade:", grade)
```